# How to request json from php script with angular2?

Tags: angular

Im really new to programming website, or even programming in general. I started learning jQuery together with php, but figured I'd learn angular instead.

So Im using something based on the Tour of Heroes course they had on the angular.io website. It gets the information using InMemoryBackendService. 
Their hero.service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero }           from './hero';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web API
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

How do I make this work with running a php script instead. I figured I could use the http.get kinda lika an AJAX function, but it's coming up with 404 - Not found when I do this (atleast when I do this how I figured it'd work).

Alternatively I was looking into using Nodejs for serverside (or anything that would work and would be useful to learn) but it all seemed so confusing and I'd have even less idea how to get it to work with angular 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what backend do you have, you just need to pass the correct url to the angular2 http.get :

```
private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web API
```

So first make sure your backend url is working by just paste it into the browser address bar.

Comment: Hmm, I must have messed something else up then. Cause thats what I did, and I tested the php script and it gives echo's the json data. Hmm, ill try to do it again. Thanks!